# Using %APPDATA% with CreateProcessW

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createprocess

I have a simple code that uses system() to download a file to AppData with the variable %APPDATA%, I want to use CreateProcessW instead of system, but for some reason when I use the same command under CreatProcess it looks for "Working Dir"\%APPDATA% instead of the actual AppData directory, and throws an exception.

System() working code:

```
system("powershell.exe -command Invoke-WebRequest https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty.exe -OutFile '%APPDATA%\\putty.exe'");
```

CreateProcessW code:

```
wchar_t cmdArgs[] = L"powershell.exe -command Invoke-WebRequest https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty.exe -OutFile '%APPDATA%\\putty.exe'";
CreateProcessW(NULL, cmdArgs, nullptr, nullptr, false, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi)
```

The exception:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Could not find a part of the path 'G:\Projects\C++\PS_Tries\PS_Tries\%APPDATA%\putty.exe'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/put ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

How can I make it expand %APPDATA% like system() does?

Comment: You can use `ExpandEnvironmentStrings`.

Comment: @VTT Ive tried using that but I don't know how to add the output to CreateProcess

Comment: That would be another question.

Comment: Expanding `%APPDATA%` is the wrong way to find the folder. You are meant to use `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I used SHGetKnownFolderPath but adding the output and inserting into the cmd line is quite messy, unless you know a simple way?

Comment: You just use `+` with a `std::wstring`. All this awful C string stuff, you don't have to live this way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan When I tried just adding the output, the heap was corrupted and an exception was thrown

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that your code is wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That exact problem was another question ive asked and people said that ShGetKnownFolder returns a heap that cannot hold a file location, but only a dir.

Comment: My code is working fine. You get the directory. You then use a `std::wstring` to build a file name based on that directory. Nobody said that you had to build the string in the memory returned by `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [_wdupenv_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/dupenv-s-wdupenv-s?view=vs-2017) function to get appdata path and then `concatenate` it with your args

```
wchar_t *w_app_data_path;
size_t sz = 0;
errno_t err = _wdupenv_s(&w_app_data_path, &sz, L"APPDATA");
wchar_t cmdArgs[2048]{ 0 };
wsprintfW(cmdArgs, L"powershell.exe -command Invoke-WebRequest https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty.exe -OutFile '%s\\putty.exe'", w_app_data_path);
free(w_app_data_path);
CreateProcessW(NULL, cmdArgs, nullptr, nullptr, false, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi)
```

Comment: You have a memory leak. You are not supposed to pass an already allocated buffer to `_wdupenv_s`. Instead, the function allocates a buffer for you, which you have to `free` when you are done using it.

Comment: @zett42 I have updated the code regarding your remark